# How to save a Canvas like an Image

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I have a Silverlight application that allows you to write with the mouse like a paint.
I am using a canvas inside a grid, and now I want to save that you draw on the canvas in a kind of file that you can open again in any time. Finally I use FileDialogs to do it.

I don´t know the way to save the canvas and neither how to open the file saved.
I have a clue, maybe writeable bitmap will be a good solution, but I didn´t find a good tutorial about it.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following:
[How save canvas as image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086550/how-save-canvas-as-image)