# How I can save an image in Canvas Control to WebSQL?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jquery-mobile, web-sql

How I can save an image in Canvas Control to WebSQL?
My application is a jQuery Mobile Application.

Here I found a clue for my answer

[How save canvas as image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086550/how-save-canvas-as-image)

var img = new WriteableBitmap(myCanvas, null);

But this img how I can Save in my WebSql database? How do I convert this if I want to save it in an SQL SERVER table(Image DataType)?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I want to know this too. I am also happy if i know how to save it on the server.
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/ is one way but it does not funktion porperly on my mobile device...

Comment: I got a solution for this. Please refer the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image we can store in web sql in 'TEXT' datatype.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
MyImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

For previewing this, this 'MyImage' dataurl can set to any Image object 'src'.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = MyImage;
```